# How to change default Xinput values?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.04, xinput

I want to disable mouse acceleration on my mouse, and would like to change it by changing the value of `libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default` from `1, 0` to `0, 1` with a command `xinput --set-prop [ID] [id of the value] 0, 1` but that returns an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

I can't create a startup application because my mouse's ID changes constantly for no reason. I also cannot change the global value of the variable because I need to have Pointer Acceleration on for my touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

### Edited:

I edit my answer to show a so much simpler aproach. You can use a device `type:name` instead of its `ID` like so:

```
xinput set-prop "keyboard:Logitech K400 Plus" "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled" 1
```

This avoids having to know the volatile `ID` field.

---

### Old answer:

I had not found a way of changing Default values of Xinput, but you
can use bash pipes to get the ID dynamically and use it in a Startup
Aplication.

As I lack the specifics of your device, I exemplify with my personal
case. I want to change some Xinput properties of my K400+ keyboard.

First you have to locate **univocally** the Xinput line that
identifies your device.

```
$ xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K400 Plus                        id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech K400 Plus                        id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So I can use the simple regex `K400.*keyboard` to get the last line
(not the pointer one). Next I `grep` this regex into a pipe, isolate
the id via `cut` utility.

```
$ xinput | grep K400.*keyboard | cut -f2 | cut -c4-
7
```

Finnaly I use it to change whatever property I want. In this case, I'm
interested in `libinput Middle Emulation Enabled`. The full command
that does this is:

```
xinput | grep K400.*keyboard | cut -f2 | cut -c4- | 
xargs -I{} xinput set-prop {} "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled" 1
```

Now you can use it as a Startup Aplication.